# Change App name dynamically based on user input

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to change the name of the app and the form title based on the user input. I know to do those changes in the manifest and styles, but how to make it dynamic. Please suggest me how to do it?. What are the changes to be done.

Comment: are you trying to change the name of the app as it appears in the android apps menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
myActivity.setTitle(userInput); //Where userInput is new title given by user
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am just confused where to implement. I have an activity page for form fields. Can I have a settings page where the user can input this? Will this override the settings in the android manifest? @Mystic

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the `setTitle()` function from within your Activity. It takes either an `int (resource ID)` or a `CharSequence` as a parameter.

or

```
this.setTitle("New Title Here");
```

or change in `manifest file`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the string in the Title bar, you can use setTitle as @android_beginner or @Mystic Magic suggested.

If you intend on changing the name of the app as it appears in the Android desktop, I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I want to change the title bar only.